# Malfunction in AppleScript from eHow to improve iCal & Outlook compatability

Tags: outlook, applescript, icalendar

eHow has an article on some Applescript that is suppose to make iCal invitations format properly in Outlook, instead of sending an ICS file.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5887667_send-ical-invites-outlook.html

However, when I follow the instructions (minus the HTML markup), after clicking compile it gives me the following error in regard to a Tell Mail command:

"Syntax Error: Expected "," or "}" but found identifier"

The same command is used throughout the script, but for some reason it is only problematic in this spot. If I delete it, I get the error "Expected """ by found end of script"

I do not know anything about AppleScript - just trying to make iCal workable for professional use.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the link your article references:
[Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031128231213827)

```
on send_mail_sbrp(subjectLine, messageText, myrecipient, invitationPath)
    set pfile to POSIX file invitationPath
    set myfile to pfile as alias

    try
        -- define a carriage return
        set cr to (ASCII character 13) & (ASCII character 10)

        -- retrieve the user's name and e-mail
        set listOfAccounts to {}

        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with oneAccount in every account
                set listOfAccounts to listOfAccounts & ¬
                    {"\"" & (get full name in oneAccount) & "\" <" & ¬
                        (get email addresses in oneAccount) & ">"}
            end repeat
        end tell

        if ((get length of listOfAccounts) is 1) then
            set theAccountTouse to get first item of listOfAccounts
        else
            set theAccountTouse to ¬
                choose from list listOfAccounts ¬
                    default items (get first item of listOfAccounts) ¬
                    with prompt ¬
                    ¬
                        "Please select which mail account to send the invitation from:" without multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed
        end if

        -- open and read the iCal event file to insert into an e-mail
        set myEventFileHandle to ¬
            open for access myfile without write permission
        set myEventFileContent to read myEventFileHandle
        close myEventFileHandle

        -- pre-pend mail headers to the event contents
        set myNewEmailText to ¬
            "Subject: " & subjectLine & cr & ¬
            "From: " & theAccountTouse & cr & ¬
            "To: " & myrecipient & cr & ¬
            "content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage" & cr & ¬
            "Content-Type: text/calendar;" & cr & ¬
            "  method=REQUEST;" & cr & ¬
            "  name=\"meeting.ics\"" & cr & ¬
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" & cr & cr & ¬
            myEventFileContent

        -- create a random event file name
        set tempMailName to (random number from 1 to 1000000) & ".ics"
        set aliasTempMail to "/tmp/" & tempMailName

        -- write the new e-mail to a temp file
        set myEventFileHandle to ¬
            open for access (POSIX file aliasTempMail as string) with write permission
        write myNewEmailText starting at 1 to myEventFileHandle
        close myEventFileHandle

        -- use SENDMAIL to send the file with proper headers
        do shell script "sendmail < " & aliasTempMail

        -- delete the temp file
        do shell script "rm " & aliasTempMail
    on error errMsg
        display dialog errMsg
    end try
end send_mail_sbrp
```